# Understanding the sources for the contributions made for the presence of electric field inside and outside the current flowing conductor

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, electric-current

Consider a setup of a battery with a current carrying conductor.

> There are three contributions to electric field outside and inside of the wire that is by.

- 1. surface charges on the conductive wire
- 2. by potential difference in the battery  which has its own field
- 3. by the moving electrons which makes the current .

> Is it true that from the surface charges and due to moving electrons the field inside the wire is zero individually? Only the uniform field inside is due to the battery potential difference itself? And a relation for that is given by $J= \sigma E$ ?

> The reasoning for the field zero, due to current electrons is that positive nuclei may be able to exactly cancel the electric field, produced by moving electrons. Although, it might not be right, since we know about the dipole which is neutral, but still has an electric field.

> On the other hand, outside the wire the field is due to surface charges only?